# Can someone tell me what I did wrong to verify my domain?

Tags: dns, mailgun, namecheap

These are the screenshots I did, I try to connect mailgun but they do not accept my ticket. Can someone help me with these problems? I don't know what I did wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: where is mail.douxirendy.net pointing to ?

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem. You should try to change your host name as below:

SPF record:

- Host name: mail

DKIM record:

- Host name: k1._domainkey.mail

MX record:

- Host name: mail

Option DNS record:

- Host name: email.mail

If my reply fixes your issue, please mark as the answer so others will know it works.

Answer (score 0):

SPF record:

```
Host name: mail
```

DKIM record:

```
Host name: k1._domainkey.mail
```

MX record:

```
Host name: mail
```